# Oracle Materialized View - Fast Refresh and WHERE

Tags: oracle, materialized-views

i have MV with code:

```
select id, name, flag from remote_table@dblink where flag = 1
```

it work, but if I want to get the flag column from the local table - the view returns a complex SQL error "cannot create a fast refresh materialized view from a complex query":

```
    select id, name, flag from remote_table@dblink 
    where flag = (select val from local_table where id = 10)
```

How to complete the record limit based on the value from the database? So that the view could be created in fast mode?